Db2 z/OS - SYSIBM.SYSTABLES.CARDF does not equal COUNT(*)
Why does this:
SELECT 
  CARDF AS "ROW_COUNT"
FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES TABLES 
WHERE TYPE = 'T' 
  AND "OWNER" = 'MY_SCHEMA'
  AND NAME = 'MY_TABLE'
;

have a different result than this:
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "ROW_COUNT"
FROM MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE
;


EDIT:
The left number in the screenshot belongs to the SYSIBM.SYSTABLES query. The right number to the COUNT query.
The table does not contain CLOBs or other BLOBs but large VARCHAR columns.

Which result belongs to which query in your example?

Cardf is a FLOAT number, which should tell you that its exact value is unimportant. Just guessing here, but it is probably used by the query optimizer to make decisions on things like full table scans vs. index scans.  The fact that it's different from the table value probably means you need to run statistics on your tables so the optimizer can make better decisions.

Yep, cardf is based on statistics.
